# Yii2 - how to get all view params passed from controller?

Tags: php, view, yii2, parameters

How can I get all params that the controller passed on to the view?

My controller says:

```
return $this->render('update', [
    'model' => $model,
    'varA' => 3,
    'varB' => 8
]);
```

Within the view `var_dump($this->params)` just returns an empty array instead of the 3 items. How can I get the entire array that was passed on?

The reason I want to do this is to pass on the params to another view with `renderPartial()` and I want to avoid specifying each parameter manually...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should simply use `$_params_` :

> The parameters (name-value pairs) that will be extracted and made available in the view file.

e.g. :

```
$this->renderPartial('view', $_params_);
```

Read more about [how php view files are rendered](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/2.0.8/framework/base/View.php#L320).